# I'm looking for a PC/Android app that emulates Android keyboard, taking input from PC keyboard

Tags: keyboard, android, bluetooth, desktop-computer, emulation

I'm sure I can't be the only one who sometimes want to use a physical keyboard to type a short (or long) paragraph of text to my Android phone, all without taking out a mobile hardware keyboard, turn on, and pair with the device, especially I'm on my computer typing on an existing, physical keyboard.

I searched.  I see many apps allowing to do the opposite: using Android device acting as a PC peripheral.  Does anyone know such app that would allow me to do what I described, optionally allowing input of any text (Chinese, Japanese etc) to my phone using my PC?

Thanks.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [Remote Keyboard App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.onyxbits.remotekeyboard&hl=en). Can't say whether it can help with other languages.

Comment: Well, what I have in mind is a convenience app with pretty much hassle free pairing between the device and the PC... definitely not anything telnet related...

Comment: not sure why you think telnet makes it so hard?